# Popover de Bootstrap no funciona en Angular

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap, angular, typescript

De Bootstrap estoy usando la clase `popover()`, hasta el momento funcionaba y quedaba en mi web así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El proyecto lo estoy migrando a Angular con el fin de aprender y tal, pero al hacerlo con el Jquery, Bootstrap y popper inyectados no me coge la clase `.popover()`

Mi angular.json:

```
"styles": [
  "src/styles.scss",
  "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
  "node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css"
],
"scripts": [
  "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
  "node_modules/popper.js/dist/popper.js",
  "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"

]
```

En HTML:

```
<div class="col col-sm-5 ml-auto popovers" id="nombrePopover" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-content="El campo Nombre ha de tener 5 carácteres mínimo">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="{{'name' | translate}}" name="usuario" id="Usuario">
</div>
```

Y mi código jQuery (Typescript) con el que implemento la función en la que manipulo dichos popovers:

```
muestraMiPopover(miPopover:any){
  console.log(miPopover);
  if(miPopover!=undefined){
      $(".popovers").popover("hide"); //Aquí falla .popover() diciendo que no existe dicha función
      miPopover.popover({ //Y aquí
          "title": 'Error',
      });
      miPopover.popover("show");
  }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Estas son mis importaciones del anterior proyecto dónde SÍ funciona:

```
<!-- FontAwsome -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Importaciones -->
<script src="../JS/Jquery/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Propias -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/sassCss/crearCuenta.css">
<!-- Favion.ico -->
<link rel="icon" href="../img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

Comment: Ya que migraste a Angular, no sería bueno dejar de lado jQuery? https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/popover/examples

Comment: en ello estoy, pero eso no soluciona mi problema

Answer (score 0):

Deberias usar ng-bootstrap, te olvidas de jquery y bootstrap.

1. Los instalas -> `npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap`
2. En el `app.module`

```
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@NgModule({
    ...
    imports: [NgbModule, ...],
    ...

})
export class YourAppModule { }
```

3. Ya puedes implementar popovers.

Un ejemplo:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary mr-2" placement="top"
    ngbPopover="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel auge laoreet rutrum faucibius." poppoverTitle="Popover on top">
</button>
```

Para mas información: [página de ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/popover/examples)

Comment: Por favor considera publicar tu código como texto pues no hay necesidad de publicarlo como imagen

Comment: Sep, eso me sirve y ya no solo eso, me vale para otras cosas como veo para los alerts, joder asi superfacil jeje

Comment: Una pregunta mas, esto me permite usar popovers, pero para llevar el control al typescript como lo harías? manipulando el DOM

Comment: Debes olvidarte de manipular el DOM cuando trabajes con angular, pues el framework se encarga de eso, mira la documentación de ng-bootstrap ahí te enseñan como llevar el control de los componentes.